# Component function works only on the first component Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, v-for

I'm learning Vue.js and as exercise i'm developing a SPA. I recursively add some icon as imgs via components. (a lot of code has been omitted to focus on the problem)

Vue.js

```
Vue.component('icon', {
  template: 
    '<img id="logo-icon" v-on:mouseover="animation" 
     class="platform_button" width="50" height="50" 
     src="../assets/img/logos/Android_icon.png" alt="img" />',

  methods: {
    animation: function(){
      animate("#logo-icon","animated bounce")
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#apps'
})

...
```

.html

```
<div id="apps">
  ...
  <div v-for="(el, in) in x" style="width:50%">
    <icon></icon>
  </div> 
  ...
</div>
```

All images are shown properly. I want to start an animation on mouse hover the image. The function to animate works fine, problem is that regardless of which image I hover with the mouse, **only the first one will bounce**. E.g. if I'm on img1 with the mouse, img1 will bounce. If I'm on img5 with the mouse, img1 will bounce instead of img5.
How can I make animate only the image covered by mouse?

Comment: The reason is `id` should be unique for each element; try to use class instead of `id`.

Comment: Which id? apps or logo-icon?

Comment: your icon component has an `id="logo-icon"`, which will be repeated for each icon component rendered. But  `id`s should be unique, which is why your `animate` function is only affecting one element when you call it on `#logo-icon`.

Comment: Now all images are bouncing when mouse is over one of them

Comment: As they are added recursively they all have same class attribute. How can i make bounce only the selected one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters pointed out, since you are applying the animation to `#logo-icon`, and you have multiple copies of your component on the page, there are multiple `img` tags that match `#logo-icon`. As such the behavior of `animate` may affect just a single element (the first) or more than one, depending on implementation.

Instead, with Vue, you can just refer to the root element via `this.$el`. This is a reference to the single specific `img` element you want to animate.

```
Vue.component('icon', {
  template: 
    '<img id="logo-icon" v-on:mouseover="animation" 
     class="platform_button" width="50" height="50" 
     src="../assets/img/logos/Android_icon.png" alt="img" />',

  methods: {
    animation: function(){
      animate(this.$el,"animated bounce")
    }
  }
})
```

What this does is apply the animation to the root element of your component. In this case, the root element is your `img`. If you had more than one element in your component you would likely need to use a ref.

Comment: this.$el is the key. Thank you Bert

Comment: @JuveLover Happy to help :)